# CSS Vertical Accordion Flip on Hover Inside Unordered List

Tags: jquery, html, css

**GOAL**
- Vertically flip accordion title divs on hover.
- Frontface and backface have exact same text and `color:`, but different `background-color:`.

**PROBLEM**
- I am using a version of this with a horizontal flip and it works, but it has differently structured code. It is not in an `ul`. It is in straight HTML divs. Applying this to an `ul` is confusing me.
- Flips vertically okay, but it is showing the front text upside down.

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/21b2r35n/

**HYPOTHESIS**
- Fiddle, above, is prior to the following
(1) I need to place a `<div class="vFront">text</div>` and `<div class="vBack">text</div>` inside the `<li>` in order to show/hide the frontor backface, but I am not doing it correctly. It breaks the animation and design when I implement it.
(2) I tried to adjust the jquery code after trying (1), above, so it would correctly find the `<a>` in order to properly animate (expand/contract), but I couldn't get it to work either. I think this code might be the culprit.

So I'm stuck :/ Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flip the `li` vertically 180° without flipping the text by adding `scaleY(-1)` to the transform:

```
.vertical.vFlipContainer:hover .vFlipper {
  transform:rotateX(-180deg) scaleY(-1);
}
```

The background of the `a` doesn't change right away, probably because of a couple factors:  inherent padding on its parent `li`, and the animation timing may be interfering with its hover style.

To fix that, let the `li` handle the background style change.  Remove `background-color` from `#drawer.courseDrawer > ul > li > a`, and use these styles:

```
.vertical.vFlipContainer .vFlipper {
  transform-origin:100% 50%;
  background-color:#FF8000;
}

.vertical.vFlipContainer:hover .vFlipper {
  transform:rotateX(-180deg) scaleY(-1);
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zgoeLs1j/1)

Comment: I like this one A LOT (thank you). Man, I really envy people's intellect on this site - so smart. Do you notice a delay on your end? If you slowly hover over a title, it flips, then a half second later the color changes. You see the cursor staying default until a half second later and then it switches to pointer. Is that simply a timing tweak I need to do in the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

change to -360 the hover efect

`.vertical.vFlipContainer:hover .vFlipper {transform:rotateX(-360deg);}`

http://jsfiddle.net/21b2r35n/1/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the "smallest" solution, but I think it'll do exactly what you want it to do. The original only has the title bar colored grey when the bar, but it still has the bar flipped when you're hovered over the expanded content. Part of my variation is that it'll have the title bar color changed for the entire time the bar is flipped, not just when you're hovered over the bar.

Modified CSS:

```
/* MISC ---- */
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:300; letter-spacing:1px; color:#4D4D4D; padding-top:0px; }
.blackColor {color:#000000 !important;}
.grayColor {color:#999999 !important;}

/* ACCORDION GENERIC ---- */
#drawer {width:100%; text-align:left; margin-top:20px;}
#drawer ul { list-style:none; padding:0;}
/*hands*/
#drawer > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content:'\f0a7 \00a0';}
#drawer > ul > li.has-sub.active > a:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content:'\f0a6 \00a0';}
/*text*/
#drawer ul ul li:nth-child(even) {padding-left:60px; font-size:14px; color:#999999; line-height:24px;}

/* ACCORDION SPECIFIC ---- */
/*title*/
#drawer.courseDrawer > ul > li > a {font-size:16px; display:block; color:#FFF; margin-top:20px; padding:10px; text-decoration:none; line-height:20px;}
#drawer.courseDrawer > ul > li > a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#FFF;}
/*heading*/
#drawer.courseDrawer ul ul li:nth-child(odd) {padding-left:30px; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:18px;}
/*dropdown*/
#drawer.courseDrawer ul ul {display:none; list-style:none; padding:10px 0 20px 0; margin:0 0 20px 0; border-left:1px solid #FF8000; border-right:1px solid #FF8000; border-bottom:1px solid #FF8000;}

/* VERTICAL FLIP ---- */
.vFlipContainer {perspective:1000px;}
.vFlipContainer, .vFront, .vBack {width:100%; height:auto;}
/* flip speed */
.vFlipper {transition:0.3s; transform-style:preserve-3d; position:relative;}
/* hide back */
.vFront, .vBack {backface-visibility:hidden; -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
/* front */
.vFront {z-index:1; background-color:#FF8000; color:#FFF;}
/* back */
.vBack {transform:rotateX(-180deg); background-color:#4FAEDD; color:#FFF; animation:vtoFront 0.3s linear normal forwards;}
.vertical.vFlipContainer {position:relative;}
.vertical.vFlipContainer:hover .vBack {animation-delay:0.3s; animation:vtoBack 0.3s linear normal  forwards;}
@keyframes vtoBack {  
  0% {z-index:0;}
  100% {z-index:1;}
}
@keyframes vtoFront {
  0% {z-index:1;}
  100% {z-index:0;}
}
.vertical.vFlipContainer .vFlipper {transform-origin:100% 50%; background-color:#FF8000;}
.vertical.vFlipContainer:hover .vFlipper {transform:rotateX(-180deg); background-color:#999999;}

.accTitle {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent !important;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Modified Accordion Item:

```
            <li class="vertical vFlipContainer" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <a class="vFlipper" href="#" onclick="return false;"></a>
                <a class="accTitle" href="#" onclick="return false;">ACCORDION 1 TITLE</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Accordion 1 Heading</li>
                    <li>Accordion 1 Text 1<br>Accordion 1 Text 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

For a quick fix, it works, and allows you to not have to transform it more than the `-180deg` you already have it set to.

Basically, I removed the `background-color` from `#drawer.courseDrawer > ul > li > a` and `#drawer.courseDrawer > ul > li > a:hover` and added it to `.vertical.vFlipContainer .vFlipper` and `.vertical.vFlipContainer:hover .vFlipper`, respectively. This allows the `background-color` change to occur at any point while the item is being hovered. Then, adding the extra `class` and `a` allows the prevention of the text flipping.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbg15rbx/

I hope this helps. ^^